# AJAX / PHP/XML - Get some datas via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

My PHP file generates XML via my database, this file works, the problem is in the JavaScript part.

**Situation** : When I type a letter, I can get the data from my XML generated by PHP.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $bdd = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sommets");
  if ($bdd->connect_error) {die("Impossible de se connecter");}
  $bdd->set_charset("utf-8");

  if (isset($_GET['recherche'])) {
     $recherche = addslashes($_GET['recherche']);
     $sql = "SELECT * from sommets where som_nom like '$recherche%'";
     $rec = $bdd->query($sql) or die($bdd->error);
     header("Content-type: text/xml");
     echo("<sommets>");
  while ($row = $rec->fetch_object()) {
      echo("<sommet altitude=\"{$row->som_altitude}\">");
      echo("<nom>{$row->som_nom}</nom>");
      echo("<region>{$row->som_nom}</region>");
      echo("</sommet>");
  }
  echo("</sommets>");  
}
?>
```

Javascript

```
<input type="text" name="r" id="recherche"/>
<div id="nom"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('recherche').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  var nom = document.getElementById("nom");
  nom.innerHTML = "";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState<4) return;
  var resultatsXML = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("sommets");
  if(resultatsXML.length > 0){
    for (var i=0; i<resultatsXML.length; i++) {
    var nom_sommet = resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[i].
                                              childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML += nom_sommet[i]
                                           .childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
 }
}
var r = document.getElementById("recherche").value;
   if(r != ""){
     xhr.open("GET", "TP09_AJAX_XML.php?recherche="+r);
     xhr.send(); 
    } else { nom.innerHTML = ""; } 
   });
```

I have this Error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

or same with "`fistChild`" or "`nodeValue`". I just want to read one bracket from my XML generated by PHP.

Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: `.childNodes[0]` isn't a tree and `.childNodes[0].childNodes` is undefined just immediately get the `.nodeValue` after  `childNodes[0]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shall use "sommet" and not "sommets" when using `xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName`.

Second, `resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[i]` is using the variable `i` for `resultatsXML` and for the results of `getElementsByTagName`. If, as first point, `resultatsXML[i]` contains a "sommet", than, as per your example, `getElementsByTagName` will return only one XML tag, so it shall be :

```
var resultatsXML = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("sommet");
if(resultatsXML.length > 0){
    for (var i=0; i<resultatsXML.length; i++) {
        var nom_sommet = resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].nodeValue;
        document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML += nom_sommet;
    }
}
```

Correct me if I did not understand correctly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Means that

```
resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[i].childNodes
```

is undefined because

```
resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[i]
```

isn't a tree plus it and you only have single value

also change `[i]` to `[0]`

```
resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0]
```

just emediately get `.nodeValue` from `resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0]`

```
var nom_sommet = resultatsXML[i].getElementsByTagName("nom")[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("nom").innerHTML += nom_sommet;
```